# Вывод HTML элементов в JS

Tags: javascript

Пока плохо разбираюсь в JS,не подскажите как решить данную задачу ну или пояснить как эту задачу решить.

При клике на `<i>` с клаcсом .itemAdd (см. приклепленый код) в конец документа должен выводится этот же код но в содержание `<h4>` должен добавлятся `<i class="close">x</i>`  тоесть выводимый код должен выглядить так `<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span><i class="close">x</i></h4>`

Но при этом значение .item_price должно остатся таким каким и было в оригинале.

```html
<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span></h4>

<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">20</span></h4>

<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">30</span></h4>
```

Comment: Задача вроде не сложная, но описаниее немного непонятное. Итак, есть на странице что то вроде "# 10". Теперь нужно, чтобы при клике на # добавлся кретик и класс менялся на 'close'? Или целиком в документ добавлась такая эе строка, но с классом close?

Answer (score 1):

Вот мое решение с комментариями:

```js
function appendDiv(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // Запрещаем всплытие событий

  // Далее само решение
  const apDiv = document.createElement('div'); // Создаем див и помещаем в переменную
  apDiv.textContent = 'Добавленный див'; // Содержание див`а
  div.appendChild(apDiv); // Помещаем див в див из разметки
}

const div = document.querySelector('div'); // Вот тот самый див из разметки, мы нашли его и поместили в переменную ссылку на него

div.addEventListener('click', appendDiv, {
  capture: true
}); // здесь мы вешаем на див из разметки событие 'click' и передаем колбеком функцию appendDiv
```

```html
<div>Нажми на меня</div>
```